# How to know when activity is laid out?

Tags: android, layout, android-mapview

I've got a mapview that I want to put some markers on top of. I'll retrieve these from a webservice when I start the activity, so I need to know the minimum and maximum lat/lng pairs for the current viewport. I'm calling

```
mMapView.getWidth()
mMapView.getHeight()
```

But they both return 0 while the activity is starting. I tried putting it in onAttachedToWindow, onResume, onPostCreate, onPostResume, onStart and so on, but to no avail. How can I know that the activity has finished laying out all the views and is ready to give me the correct height and width measurements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to override [onSizeChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) and call getWidth/Height from there. Be aware though that onSizeChanged might get called multiple times during your activity's lifecycle (Everytime the size of the view changes).

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of doing that. But it solved my problem! :)

Answer (score 6):

From [this post](http://markmail.org/message/ktepiitxu4335r27) that I've found googling:

> Assuming your view is visible, its
>   size has been assigned by the time the
>   activity's window receives focus. That
>   is, when activity.onWindowFocusChanged
>   is called with hasFocus = true.
>
> The sequence is roughly:
>
> view.onFinishInflate
>
> view.onMeasure
>
> view.onSizeChanged(width, height, 0, 0)
>
> view.onLayout
>
> activity.onWindowFocusChanged(true)

I tried and it worked.

**EDIT**

I've found that it's probably better using a `ViewTreeObserver`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142090/how-do-you-to-retrieve-dimensions-of-a-view-getheight-and-getwidth-always-re/4406090#4406090).