# How to determine the height of TextView programmatically?

Tags: android

I have created an xml for a row of listview. It has just one Textview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="A">
</TextView>
```

I need to determine the height of this textview programmatically.
If I code textview.getTextSize(): this just returns the size of text.

Edit:

I am want to retrieve the height of the textview prior to rendering this on the screen. I mean, I want to inflate this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(this);
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
TextView row_textview=((TextView)view);
```

and then calculate the height of "row_textview" instance.

Comment: Please improve your accept rating. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: If you want to retrieve textview's height, I think it must be there on Screen. Otherwise you can try getting height of another view,

Comment: you can get height of TextView using txtview1.getLayoutParams() method.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try

[`textview.getHeight();`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getHeight%28%29)

> Return the height of your view.

Or this

[`textview.getMaxHeight();`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getMaxHeight%28%29)

> the maximum height of this TextView expressed in pixels, or -1 if the
>   maximum height was set in number of lines instead using or
>   [setLines(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setMaxLines%28int%29).

Comment: getMaxheight is not  there in the API of TextView, I think. getHeight os returning 0.

Comment: for `getHeight()` returning 0, probably you are taking the height in wrong place. Google it and you will get enough reasons for this.

Comment: Ok. `getMaxHeight()` was introduced in API 16 only

Comment: Its not about wrong place, its all about retrieving the height before the view is rendered on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getHeight%28%29) and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getLineHeight%28%29)?

`txtview.getHeight();`

> Returns The height of your view, in pixels.

Or

```
txtview.getLineHeight();
```

> Returns the height of one standard line in pixels. Note that markup
>   within the text can cause individual lines to be taller or shorter
>   than this height, and the layout may contain additional first- or
>   last-line padding.

Comment: getLineHeight is returning 24 pixels as the value. While, when I have overriden the onSizeChanged() method of Textview which prints accurately the height and width of the textview, it prints 29. This means that there is some padding/margin which getLineHeight is not considering while calculating the height. Also, getLineHeight calculates the height of line in pixels, I dont think this calculates the total height of the textview.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get height and width for textView--

```
 textView.getMeasuredWidth();

 textView.getMeasuredHeight();
```

Comment: getMeasuredHeight and getHeight both are returning 0 (zero). I have already tried this. The reason is I am calculating the metrics before the view is rendered on the screen. I forgot to add this in my question, so I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find any answer to this question, so I am not accepting any answer provided so far on this thread.
Since I am trying to calculate the height of the textview before it is rendered on the screen,  by reading the xml layout, this is not supported in Android. In this case, we have to hard core the height measure and then convert this dp measure to pixel at runtime.
[Get the height of a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912687/android-get-the-height-of-the-textview)
This link can be useful for others who are searching the answer for this.