# getWidth and getHeight are returning a zero

Tags: android, view

I am trying to make a simple drawing program for the android.

I have a custom `View` class to handle the drawing. When I call its `getWidth` and `getHeight` metheds, I get a zero.

But, the drawing works fine, I hard code in the width and height so it works.  Why is it doing this?

---

**My View class**

```
public class cDrawing extends View{

    char BitMap[];
    static final short WIDTH=160;
    static final short HEIGHT=440;
    static final char EMPTY=' ';
    int mWidthSize;
    int mHeightSize;

    static final char RED ='R';
    int y;

    public cDrawing(Context context) {
        super(context);

        y=3;
        // set up our bitmap
        BitMap=new char[WIDTH*HEIGHT];
        for(int i=0; i<WIDTH*HEIGHT; i++)
                BitMap[i]=EMPTY;


        // returns zero why???????
        int h=getHeight();
        h=400;
        int w=getWidth();
        w=320;
        mWidthSize=w/WIDTH;
        mHeightSize=h/HEIGHT;


        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
```

---

**The Activity class**

```
public class cCanves extends Activity  implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.canves);
        cDrawing board=new cDrawing(this);


        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.parent2);
        layout.addView(board);


        // set up buttons
        View mEraser = findViewById(R.id.buteraser);
        mEraser.setOnClickListener(this);

        View mBlack = findViewById(R.id.butblack);
        mBlack.setOnClickListener(this);

        View mWhite = findViewById(R.id.butwhite);
        mWhite.setOnClickListener(this);

        View mRed = findViewById(R.id.butred);
        mRed.setOnClickListener(this);

    } // end function

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i;
        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.buteraser:
            break;
        case R.id.butblack:
            break;
        case R.id.butwhite:
            break;
        case R.id.butred:
            break;
        } // end switch

    }   // function
}
```

---

**the xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/buteraser"
      android:src="@drawable/icon"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/butblack"
      android:src="@drawable/icon"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/butwhite"
      android:src="@drawable/icon"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/butred"
      android:src="@drawable/icon"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/parent2"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'll refer you to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142090/how-do-you-to-retrieve-dimensions-of-a-view-getheight-and-getwidth-always-re/4406090#4406090).

Comment: You have to wait until your view has been instantiated and given its dimensions. Everything should be ready by the onDraw function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you to retrieve dimensions of a view? Getheight() and Getwidth() always return zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142090/how-do-you-to-retrieve-dimensions-of-a-view-getheight-and-getwidth-always-r)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The width and height are not defined until the view is actually rendered to the screen.

Use [protected abstract void onLayout (boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onLayout%28boolean,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) (which you override in your activity) to know when the sizes are ready.

Comment: Thank you,i have another program where thius works fine, i'll see if I'm doing it after the view iks displayed

Comment: As answered by Ginsan below, onLayout is the best place to call the getHeight and getWidth methods.

Answer (score 6):

Complementing Mah's answer, I found out that you can get the values from parameters, like the code bellow:

```
ImageView imageProcess = (ImageView) li.inflate(
    R.layout.andamento_sinistro_imageprocess, centerLayout, false);
imageProcess.setBackgroundResource(
    (isActive)?(R.drawable.shape_processon):(R.drawable.shape_processoff));
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageProcessParams = 
    (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)imageProcess.getLayoutParams();
imageProcessParams.leftMargin = 
    (int) (centerPosition - 0.5*imageProcessParams.width);
imageProcessParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
centerLayout.addView(imageProcess);
```

The real catch here is the use of the LayoutParams, that have rules yet not processed by the element.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain, but it may have something to do with where the code is in the [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) of your activity. If you're calling `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` before the View is displayed on screen, you'll get a value of 0. I've had that happen to me, too.

I'm not sure if there's a way around this. I had to rely on getting the hardware screen's width and height, instead of the view's width and height. You might end up having to approximate the width and height of your view and hard coding it.

Comment: The drawing of the layout onto the screen is **not** directly related to the `Activity` lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

You should call **getWidth()** and **getHeight()** in the overrided method **onLayout**.

Comment: This is the exactly what should have been the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Just Use the getViewTreeObserver() Listener, and inside this just
>   calculate the height and width.
>
> Follow the code :

`getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                //Do your Stuff calculation , like view.getWidth() ...
        });`

Answer (score -6):

The view only has dimensions after beeing displayed for the first time.

Other thing:

```
int h=getHeight();
h=400;
```

Is useless no ? Is it just for testing ?