# How to know size of progress bar?

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to place spinning wheel progress bar at (x, y) location in relative layout.
To do that, I have to know the size of progress bar.
How do I know size of progress bar?
Is there better way than this?

```
ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(context, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall);
params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.leftMargin = x - pb.getWidth() / 2;  // pb.getWidth() returns 0
params.topMargin = y - pb.getHeight() / 2;
addView(pb, params);
```

Answer (score 0):

The width and height are not defined until the view rendered to the screen.
In your case it should look like this:

```
addView(pb, params);
leftMargin = x - pb.getWidth() / 2;  // pb.getWidth() returns 0
topMargin = y - pb.getHeight() / 2;
```

[Duplicate 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/android-get-width-returns-0)
[Duplicate 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145001/android-getwidth-and-getheight-are-returning-a-zero)

Comment: probably you could setWidth before