# Drawing a bitmap with relative layout returns illegalargumentexception

Tags: android, layout, bitmap, android-relativelayout

I am trying to create a bitmap out of a relative layout that i have created programmatically.
The Realtivelayout is showing as expected but when i try to create a bitmap , it returns illegal argument exception that height and width must be  > 0
this is how i am doing it

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(saveLayout.getWidth(),
            saveLayout.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Any pointers?

**Edit:** added this code, too:

```
    ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = saveLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
    if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
        viewTreeObserver
                .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        saveLayout.getViewTreeObserver()
                                .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                        viewWidth = saveLayout.getWidth();
                        viewHeight = saveLayout.getHeight();

                    }
                });
    }
```

In above given code `onGlobalLayout()` also never seemed to be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're programmatically creating the `saveLayout`, you may be asking for its width and height *too early*. (just an educated guess, because I can't see the rest of your code)

[See this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6145113/119114)

[The reason why that createBitmap() call throws that exception is:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config%29)

> if the width or height are <= 0

So, try to defer creating the `Bitmap` until **after** the view appears, or find another way to calculate the width/height.

[This question has a few options/answers for how to defer this calculation to avoid 0 results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6939002/119114)

Comment: Hey , Thanks for the help
Now i am trying to use this code to get width and height 
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = saveLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
  if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
   viewTreeObserver
     .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
      @Override
      public void onGlobalLayout() {
       saveLayout.getViewTreeObserver()
         .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
       viewWidth = saveLayout.getWidth();
       viewHeight = saveLayout.getHeight();

      }
     });
but on global layout never seemed to be called , can you tell why?

Comment: Please post additional code into your **question** above (using the **edit** link below it), and format it as code.  It's really hard to read what you just posted here.  Thanks.

Comment: does it at least get inside the `isAlive()` call, to add the new listener?  Also, see [this question for some issues with this, as well as some other alternative solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4406090/119114)

Comment: well yes it is getting inside the isalive() call.

Comment: It's hard to say ... of the code I can see, I don't see anything else wrong.  Did you also try the `onWindowFocusChanged()` method shown in the last link I provided?  And, just to double-check, you are determining that `onGlobalLayout()` is **not** called by setting a breakpoint in that method, and not seeing it hit?

Comment: Thanks for the help , looks like i wasnt calling onwindowfocuschange properly. Thanks :)