# Android property animation relative to view's height

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator

I initialize ObjectAnimator like this;

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationY", 0f, view.getHeight());
```

But when the first time animation runs, view.getHeight() method returns 0. So it does not animate. Second time i run the animation, it animates right. Is there a way to translate views  relative to their width or height properly?

Comment: maybe you have your view set after the anim object? if it's empty, it may have 0 height, and then you ex. add a picture to it and it gets different height

Comment: This answer may be helpful.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268915/views-getwidth-and-getheight-returning-0?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Initial visibility of the view is "gone". I make the view visible when animation start. But this time getHeight() method returns 0.

Comment: do you make it visible before or after animation starts?

Comment: I tried. Still getHeight() returns 0.

Comment: what about that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145001/getwidth-and-getheight-are-returning-a-zero?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Thank you. Found the answer calling view.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED); and after view.getMeasuredHeight() returns the right height value.