# Starting and stopping animation

Tags: java, android, animation

I am trying to figure out how on earth i can start and stop animation in my Android App.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    stopOneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStopOne);
    stopTwoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStopTwo);
    stopThreeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStopThree);
    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);

    firstImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    firstImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spin_animation);

    frameAnimation = new AnimationDrawable();
    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) firstImage.getBackground();
//  frameAnimation.start();

    firstImage.post(new Starter());

    stopOneButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    stopTwoButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    stopThreeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

class Starter implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        frameAnimation.start();
    }

}
```

This is pretty much everything i have, and im starting from scratch without binding any buttons to the functionality, but the image is not spinning around at all.

This is my XML file for the drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <animation-list
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image1" android:duration="500" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image2" android:duration="500" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image3" android:duration="500" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image4" android:duration="500" />
 </animation-list>
```

More code for buttons:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonStopOne:

        break;

        case R.id.buttonStopTwo:
        break;

        case R.id.buttonStopThree:
        break;

        case R.id.buttonStart:
            frameAnimation.start();
        break;
    }
}
```

Can anyone determine what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply the animation to a View.  So assuming `firstImage()` is the animation you want to animate, call `firstImage.startAnimation(frameAnimation)`.  Then to end it call `firstImage.clearAnimation()`.

**EDIT:**

Ok.  Now that I see what you're doing, I'm guessing the `Runnable` you're using is never being called.  What you can try is wait until the view has been fully inflated and start the animation in that.  Something like this:

```
firstImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
final AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) firstImage.getBackground();
ViewTreeObserver treeObserver = firstImage.getViewTreeObsver();
treeObvserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener(){
   @Override
   public void onGlobalLayout(){
      frameAnimation.start();
   }
}
```

Now, I haven't tried this, but what I'm thinking will happen is when the view is fully inflated and visible, the animation will start.

Side-note:  [It's also a handy way to figure out when the views have their dimensions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142090/how-do-you-to-retrieve-dimensions-of-a-view-getheight-and-getwidth-always-r)

Comment: I find that a bit confusing, does `frameAnimation.start();`not start my animation?

Comment: Another way to start an animation is to call `setAnimation` on the `View`, pass in the animation, then call `start()` on the animation itself.  So in your case it would be `firstimage.setAnimation(frameAnimation);` somewhere in the set.  Then when you want the animation to play called `frameAnimation.start()`.  I'm almost certain the reason it's not animating for you is that the animation is not referencing any view.

Comment: Oh wait.  I think I see what you're doing.  You're creating a drawable with an animation-list and setting it as a background.  I'm sorry. This answer won't help.  My other guess is your runnable is never being called.  I'll edit my answer because I think I have an idea.

Comment: Using post just adds a runnable to the View's message queue.  It doesn't automatically get called.  The edit in my code *should* ensure that it will always get called automatically.  If not please tell me because I haven't tried.

Comment: Thanks DeeV. But what if we instead assume that i want to implement the start and stop by button press? Then it should no longer be an issue?

Comment: If by button press, then implement an `onClickListener()` on the button and call `frameAnimation.start()` within that, so yes.

Comment: Please check my last piece of code! Thats the implementation with the button. Nothing happens when i press the start button.

Comment: Replace `AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) firstImage.getBackground();` with just `frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) firstImage.getBackground();` and remove `frameAnimation = new AnimationDrawable();`  You're not calling `start()` on the global reference.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt! Its starting to piss me off :-)