# Get value defined in dimens.xml

Tags: android, resources

The `dimens.xml` file that comes with the `Android` platform (located in the data\res\values directory) defines a dimension named action_button_min_width (value is 56dip).

Is there a way I can get this value programatically than hard-coding it in my code?

---

The suggestions and duplicate references seem to address getting a value from the resources the I've defined in my own app.  My question pertains to getting a value from a resource that is part of Android.  When I try the following getResources().getString(android.R.dimen.action_button_min_width);  I get a compile error because action_button_min_width is not defined.

Comment: Did you tried searching? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121028/load-dimension-value-from-res-values-dimension-xml-from-source-code

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getResources()`

Try this:

```
String butMinWidth = getResources().getString(R.dimen.action_button_min_width);
```

**OR:**

```
int butMinWidth = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.action_button_min_width);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The suggestions and duplicate references seem to address getting a value from the resources the I've defined in my own app.  My question pertains to getting a value from a resource that is part of the Android platform.  When I try the following getResources().getString(android.R.dimen.action_button_min_width);  I get a compile error because action_button_min_width is not defined.

Comment: please check import for R

Answer (score 0):

1)     `float value = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.action_button_min_width);`

you need to create dimens.xml file :

```
<resources>
...
    <dimen name="action_button_min_width">56dp</dimen>
...
</resources>
```

**or**

2) String `value = getResources().getString(R.dimen.action_button_min_width);`

you need to create `values/Strings.xml` file :

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
...
    <dimen name="action_button_min_width">56dp</dimen>
...
</resources>
```

Comment: I was hoping to get the value defined in the Android platform resource file rather than defining my own resource.