# Keep Custom Android Google Map Markers from Scaling

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

An app that I work on has a bus prediction feature. In this feature we have a Google Map the displays a selected bus route as a `Polyline` and uses custom flat `Marker`s. The problem is that on our [Sony Xperia M (C1904)](http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_xperia_m-5497.php) (running Jelly Bean 4.3), the `Marker`s are huge. (Screenshots below. Had to black some stuff out because of corporate) I'm including screenshots of the same code on a Nexus 5 (running KitKat 4.4.4) and a Nexus 6P (running Marshmallow 6.0.1).

**Sony Xperia M (Jelly Bean)**

[image: Xperia M Screenshot]

**Nexus 5 (KitKat)**

[image: Nexus 5 Screenshot]

**Nexus 6P (Marshmallow)**

[image: Nexus 6P Screenshot]

As you can see, the higher-resolution screen has smaller markers and the relatively low resolution Xperia M has huge markers. Is there any way to make them appear to be the same size on every device?

Here's my `Bitmap` that I build:

```
public Bitmap getStopBitmapForRoute(BusDataProvider.BusRoute route) {
        BitmapFactory.Options myOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        myOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;// important
        myOptions.inMutable = true;

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(BusFragment.outCircleRadius * 4, BusFragment.outCircleRadius * 4, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Log.d("Is Stop Bitmap Mutable?", bitmap.isMutable() + "");

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(route.getRouteColor());
        canvas.drawCircle(BusFragment.outCircleRadius, BusFragment.outCircleRadius, BusFragment.outCircleRadius, paint);

        return bitmap;
    }
```

Here's the code that actually sets the `Marker` with its other options:

```
public Marker drawStop(CyRideDataProvider.StopLocation stop, GoogleMap map) {
        Marker marker;
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
           .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getStopBitmapForRoute(currentRoute)))
           .flat(true).anchor(0.25f, 0.25f).visible(true).position(stop.getLatLng());

        routeStopMarkers.put(marker = map.addMarker(markerOptions), stop);
        displayedStops.add(new Pair<>(marker, stop));
        return marker;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using dimens.xml will probably solve it, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16276351/4409409

Comment: @DanielNugent I think you're probably right but my boss's priorities have shifted so I haven't gotten a chance to try it yet. I'll let you know if it works as soon as I can so you can put it as an answer and I can accept it. Just letting you know that I haven't forgotten this question. ;D