# Android binding adapter passing multiple arguments cause error

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am quite new in `Android Data Binding`. I am following this tutorial: [Data Binding Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html). 
I am trying to do an adapter that receive multiple parameters. This is my code:

**XML**

```
   <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/place_holder_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/place_holder_size"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            app:url="@{image.imageUrl}"
            app:size="@{@dimen/place_holder_size}"
            />
```

**BINDING ADAPTER CLASS**

```
public class ViewBindingAdapters extends BaseObservable {

@BindingAdapter({"bind:url", "bind:size"})
public static void loadImage(ImageView imageView, String url, int size) {
    if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(url)) {
        Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).load(url).resize(size, size).centerCrop().into(imageView);
    }
}
....


}
```

But I am getting this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:url' with parameter type java.lang.String on android.widget.ImageView.
>   file:... li_image_item.xml
>   loc:30:27 - 30:40
>   ****\ data binding error ****

Does anybody know why??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the datatype of `image.imageUrl`?

Comment: It is a string.

Comment: "bind:url", "bind:size" != app:url, app:size

Comment: @pskink its ok if you write `bind:url` or `url` in `BindingAdapter`, you can access both with `app:url`

Comment: In the tutorial they do it like this, in the paragraph:  Custom Setters.

Comment: yes indeed: `'''Custom namespaces are ignored during matching'''`, is `image.imageUrl` a String?

Comment: This method used to work like this: @BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
    public static void loadImage(ImageView imageView, String url) {
        if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(url)) {
            Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).load(url).into(imageView);
        }
    }.  But adding the new parameters is not working anymore. So the problem is not this image.imageUrl.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Problem is `@dimen/place_holder_size`, it returns `float` while you are catching it as `int`

change you `BindingAdapter` method to this

```
@BindingAdapter({"bind:url", "bind:size"})
public static void loadImage(ImageView imageView, String url, float size) {

}
```

you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121028/load-dimension-value-from-res-values-dimension-xml-from-source-code)

Comment: If i set change url value then it calls this method and when i set size value then this method is called again. Is there any way that it calls only once when both values are set

Answer (score 25):

What I did wrong is the order of the arguments in the function. You can add multiple attributes in Binding Adapter, but **they should match the arguments with the same sequence defined in the method**.

Here is my code snippet for Kotlin

```
@BindingAdapter(value = ["bind:brand", "bind:model", "bind:age"], requireAll = false)
@JvmStatic
fun bindProductDetails(linearLayout: LinearLayout, brand: String?, model: String?, age: String?) {
    if (brand != null && !brand.isEmpty()) {
        //code
        //code

    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

try this

```
 @BindingAdapter(value={"url", "size"}, requireAll=false)
 public static void loadImage(ImageView imageView, String url, int size) {
        if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(url)) {
            Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).load(url).resize(size, size).centerCrop().into(imageView);
        }
    }
```

Comment: just clean and rebuild project bcoz sometime studio not update it still it not work try it with invalid catches or restart ur IDE(may be stupid bt it works sometime)

Answer (score 6):

Apart from the example provided above by @Kishan Solanki, And with changes happening in the Data Binding library, all you need is to declare them with comma separated values. Example

```
@BindingAdapter("loadImageFrom", "widthDp")
fun loadImages(imageView: ImageView, url: String?, widthDp: Int) {
    url?.let {

        val height = (widthDp / 3) * 4
        val fullUrl = getImagePosterUrl(url)
        Picasso.get().load(fullUrl).resize(widthDp.px, height.px).into(imageView)
    }

}
```

Bu the most important thing to remember is that you provide the data to the adapter attributes, in the DataBinding format.

example to provide Int as parameter in XML you have to write

```
app:widthDp="@{120}"
```

which is

> app:your_attribute="@{your_data}"

P. S. - Oh and one more thing, widthDp**.px** is an extension function which converts `Int` of a dp value to relevant pixels value based on screen density. So don't get confused.

Answer (score 5):

#### Update

You don't need to create prefix `bind:`, just use this.

```
@BindingAdapter({"url", "size"})
public static void loadImage(ImageView imageView, String url, float size) {

}
```

In xml use any prefix like `app:`

```
app:url="@{image.imageUrl}"
```

Answer (score 5):

See https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters.

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl", "placeholder", requireAll = false)
fun ImageView.setImageUrl(url: String?, placeHolder: Drawable?) {
    if (url == null) {
        setImageDrawable(placeholder)
    } else {
        MyImageLoader.loadInto(this, url, placeholder)
    }
}
```

Note that `BindingAdapter` attributes and `setImageUrl` parameters may have different names. But they should go in the same order. If some of these attributes are defined in XML (in this example it is `ImageView`), this method will be called.

```
<ImageView 
    app:imageUrl="@{venue.imageUrl}"
    app:placeholder="@{@drawable/venueError}" />
```

Attributes should have the same types as defined in the method. You can also use [listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45288013/use-done-button-on-keyboard-in-databinding). Instead of Kotlin lambdas use [interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46971445/android-databinding-bindingadapter-in-kotlin-does-not-recognize-lambdas).

This class should be put in the same module with XML. Otherwise you will get an error like `AAPT: error: attribute imageUrl (aka com.example.imageUrl) not found.`.