# Use Done button on Keyboard in Databinding

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am trying to use the done button of the soft keyboard to activate a method via databinding. Just like onClick. Is there a way to do that?

example:

```
<EditText               
    android:id="@+id/preSignUpPg2EnterPhone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    onOkInSoftKeyboard="@{(v) -> viewModel.someMethod()}"
    />
```

onOkInSoftKeyboard doesn't exists... Is there something to create this behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: are you looking something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004344/how-do-i-handle-imeoptions-done-button-click  or is it some thing else?

Comment: It is clearly something else... The answer you presented doesn't use databinding, it uses a listener. I would like databinding to active a behavior. Please don't down vote a question unless you are really sure it is duplicated

Comment: Just to be clear I DID NOT downvote your question.. and by databinding what exactly you are trying to do is still unclear, could you please explain what you are trying to achieve (also it would be better if you show us what you have tried)

Comment: Sorry Firoz, I did not mean you as the down voter... I was just saying for anyone reading the coment. Thanks for trying to help me in this question! I updated the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I won't claim to be an expert in `onEditorAction()` or soft keyboard. That said, assuming you use the solution to the stack overflow question Firoz Memon suggested, you can make it happen. Even if there is another solution that works better, this can give you an idea on how to add your own event handlers.

You'd need a binding adapter that takes some kind of handler. Let's assume you have an empty listener like this:

```
public class OnOkInSoftKeyboardListener {
    void onOkInSoftKeyboard();
}
```

Then you need a BindingAdapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("onOkInSoftKeyboard") // I like it to match the listener method name
public static void setOnOkInSoftKeyboardListener(TextView view,
        final OnOkInSoftKeyboardListener listener) {
    if (listener == null) {
        view.setOnEditorActionListener(null);
    } else {
        view.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                // ... solution to receiving event
                if (somethingOrOther) {
                    listener.onOkInSoftKeyboard();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: @LeandroBorgesFerreira, Can post the full code here? I am getting databinding errors while trying to implement it.

Comment: hey how to pass listener in xml

Comment: this is all boilerplate stuff that isn't needed at all if you use the adapter generated by TextViewBindingAdapter.java -see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49375084/3175580

Answer (score 15):

Using Kotlin, kapt produces:

```
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Listener class kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1 with method invoke did not match signature of any method viewModel::signIn
```

(because `viewModel::signIn` is of type `KFunction1`) so we can't use a method reference. However, if we create a variable within the `viewModel` that is explicit about the type, then we can pass that variable as the binding's param. (or just use a class)

Bindings.kt:

```
@BindingAdapter("onEditorEnterAction")
fun EditText.onEditorEnterAction(f: Function1<String, Unit>?) {

    if (f == null) setOnEditorActionListener(null)
    else setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->

        val imeAction = when (actionId) {
            EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE,
            EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND,
            EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO -> true
            else -> false
        }

        val keydownEvent = event?.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER 
            && event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN

        if (imeAction or keydownEvent)
            true.also { f(v.editableText.toString()) }
        else false
    }
}
```

MyViewModel.kt:

```
fun signIn(password: String) {
    Toast.makeText(context, password, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

val signIn: Function1<String, Unit> = this::signIn
```

layout.xml:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    app:onEditorEnterAction="@{viewModel.signIn}"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone|actionSend|actionGo"
    android:singleLine="true"/>
```

Comment: also, you can use lambda like and remove the signIn Function1 from viewModle

fun EditText.onEditorEnterAction(block: ((password: String) -> Unit)?) { ... 
    block(password)
}

Comment: @OmarAbdan, then how to use this function in XML?

Comment: Thanks, it works. Don't forget to remove `android:inputType="textMultiLine"`, maybe set `android:maxLines="1"` and `android:singleLine="true"`.

Comment: For multiline see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986387/multi-line-edittext-with-done-action-button.

Answer (score 9):

Just as i was looking at this myself, here a simpler version where the function is directly called from the data binding:

In your ViewModel use this function:

```
 public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
return false; // if you want the default action of the actionNext or so on
return true; // if you want to intercept
}
```

And in the layout:

```
android:onEditorAction="@{(view,actionId,event) -> viewModel.onEditorAction(view,actionId,event)}"
```

Comment: KeyEvent event return null!

Comment: unknown attribute onEditorAction @Tosa

Comment: it does say that in the editor but works fine like this for me when the app is running.@free_style

Comment: @Tosa, event is null always

Comment: @SajadRahmanipour and it is not null when you implement the listener like from the marked answer? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener

Comment: This is the correct thing to do since it leverages the adapters provided by data binding, in TextViewBindingAdapter.java: `        @BindingMethod(type = TextView.class, attribute = "android:onEditorAction", method = "setOnEditorActionListener")`

Comment: This wont work: cannot find method onEditorAction(android.widget.TextView, int, android.view.KeyEvent) because we are passing in EditText not TextView. Even though it extends TextView it still fails.

Answer (score 3):

**Kotlin, without writing custom binding adapter**

In Layout,

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:onEditorAction="@{(view, actionId, event) -> viewModel.onDoneClicked(view, actionId, event)}" />
```

ViewModel

```
fun onDoneClicked(view: View, actionId: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
    if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
        // handle here
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

**Note:** `event` can be null, so make `KeyEvent` nullable by putting `?` there.

Comment: @AhmadAbdullah For me it worked this way. There might be something missing or may be some other concern.

Comment: Thank you @gprathour , it's worked, I just had a mistake in the function return type

Comment: @AhmadAbdullah That's good to know. The errors shown for data binding are sometimes weird and not easy to understand what exactly is the error. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call login method what inside ViewModel by implementing `setOnEditorActionListener` to the Edittext, taking reference from binging class

```
loginFragmentBinding.etPassword.setOnEditorActionListener(TextView.OnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            loginViewModel.login()
            return@OnEditorActionListener true
        }
        false
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Android framework already have this implemented. Take a look at [TextViewBindingAdapter](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/master/extensions/baseAdapters/src/main/java/android/databinding/adapters/TextViewBindingAdapter.java#53)

You'll see those attributes, [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters#specify-method) kind of glosses over what this means, but in a nutshell:

- `attribute` = when this attribute appears in a layout file
- `type` = then look for the implementation in this class
- `method` = of a method with this name in the class defined in type

For more on this take a look at [this blog post](https://zarah.dev/2019/02/15/framework-binders.html).