# Android DataBinding: @BindingAdapter in Kotlin does not recognize lambdas

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

This is my `BindingAdapter`:

```
@BindingAdapter(value = *arrayOf("bind:commentsAdapter", "bind:itemClick", "bind:avatarClick", "bind:scrolledUp"), requireAll = false)    
fun initWithCommentsAdapter(recyclerView: RecyclerView, commentsAdapter: CommentsAdapter,
                        itemClick: (item: EntityCommentItem) -> Unit,
                        avatarClick: ((item: EntityCommentItem) -> Unit)?,
                        scrolledUp: (() -> Unit)?) {
    //Some code here
}
```

`initWithCommentsAdapter` is a top level function

This is my layout (an essential part):

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

           <data>
               <variable
                   name="viewModel"
                   type="some.example.path.CommentsViewModel"/>
               <variable
                   name="commentsAdapter"
                   type="some.example.path.CommentsAdapter"/>
           </data>

           <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                ...
                bind:avatarClick="@{(item) -> viewModel.avatarClick(item)}"
                bind:itemClick="@{viewModel::commentClick}"
                bind:commentsAdapter="@{commentsAdapter}"
                bind:isVisible="@{viewModel.commentsVisibility}"
                bind:scrolledUp="@{() -> viewModel.scrolledUp()}"
            />
</layout>
```

When I assign lambda with kotlin method call in the layout, I have such error during building:

```
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:cannot find method avatarClick(java.lang.Object) 
in class some.example.path.CommentsViewModel
****\ data binding error ****
```

or if I assign method by reference:

```
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Listener class kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1 
with method invoke did not match signature of any method viewModel::commentClick
file:C:\Android\Projects\...\fragment_comments.xml
loc:70:12 - 83:17
****\ data binding error ****
```

But I have such methods with proper type, not Object

**Question**

How can I assign Kotlin lambda for custom @BindingAdapter in Kotlin in the layout?

**Edit**

The relevant part of the viewModel:

```
class CommentsViewModel(model: CommentsModel): BaseObservable() {
    //Some binded variables here
    ...
    fun commentClick(item: EntityCommentItem) {
        //Some code here
    }

    fun avatarClick(item: EntityCommentItem) {
        //Some code here
    }
    fun scrolledUp() {
        //Some code here
    }
    ...
}
```

The variables binding works just fine

Comment: Could you add the relevant parts of `CommentsViewModel`?

Comment: I added some relevant code from the viewModel class

Comment: Types the same as in the BindingAdapter

Comment: Did you find a fix?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I used workaround. I just pass an object with some methods. But it was a long time ago. I already forgot about it.

Comment: I try not to use @BindingAdapter at all. Just somehow no longer needed

Comment: bind:avatarClick="@{(item) -> viewModel.avatarClick(item)}" where did you got item instance in lambda?

Answer (score 39):

**Short Answer**

Instead of using Kotlin generic lambda types, use **interfaces** with a single method that matches both return type and parameters of your method reference (`itemClick`) or your listener (`avatarClick`).
You can also use abstract classes with a single abstract method, also with matching parameters and return type.

**Explanation**

Actually the [Databinding docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#method_references) never mention that the Kotlin lambda types work as Databinding listeners or method references, probably because under the hood these lambda types translate to Kotlin's `Function1`, `Function2`... which are generics, and thus some of their type information doesn't make it to the executable and therefore is not available at runtime.

Why your `scrolledUp` binding did work though? Because type `() -> Unit` has no need for generics. It could have worked even with `Runnable`.

**Code**

```
interface ItemClickInterface {
    // method may have any name
    fun doIt(item: EntityCommentItem)
}

@BindingAdapter(
    value = ["commentsAdapter", "scrolledUp", "itemClick", "avatarClick"],
    requireAll = false
)
fun initWithCommentsAdapter(
    view: View,
    commentsAdapter: CommentsAdapter,
    scrolledUp: () -> Unit,            // could have been Runnable!
    itemClick: ItemClickInterface,
    avatarClick: ItemClickInterface
) {
    // Some code here
}
```

Comment: Is there any relevant official documentation? If so, could you give me a link?

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same case, and what worked was having it declared as variable defining its type, that worked with the compiler

`val avatarClick:(item: EntityCommentItem)->Unit = {}`

Comment: this is the answer but more information is missing

Comment: It's been a while but I believe the argument ends up being declared as a handler..

avatarClick:(item: EntityCommentItem)->Unit = {}