# Issue with higher order function as a binding adapter

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin, higher-order-functions

I am running into issues trying to take a function as a parameter in a binding adapter using Kotlin/Android databinding. This example code throws `e: error: cannot generate view binders java.lang.StackOverflowError` when building with no other useful info in the log.

Here is my binding adapter:

```
@JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter("onDelayedClick")
fun onDelayedClick(view: View, function: () -> Unit) {
    // TODO: Do something
}
```

XML:

```
        <View
            android:id="@+id/test_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:onDelayedClick="@{() -> viewModel.testFunction()}"/>
```

and method in my ViewModel:

```
fun testFunction() = Unit
```

I have been struggling with this for a bit now and nothing I've tried works, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try looking at the generated databinding code. I don't think what you are trying to achieve will work because you can't use lambdas

Comment: @Chisko are you sure that you can't use lambdas ? Then how works the default onClick?

Comment: You absolutely can use lambdas and Kotlin function parameters, it's just the return type of `Unit` that causes an issue.

Comment: I said *I think* hehe, yeah, my bad, you sure can

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `function: Runnable` instead of `function: () -> Unit`.

Android's data-binding compiler generates java code, to which, your kotlin function's signature looks like `void testFunction()`, as kotlin adapts Unit as void when calling from java.

On the other hand, `() -> Unit` looks like `kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0` which is a function which takes 0 inputs and returns Unit.INSTANCE.

As you can see these two function signatures don't match, and that's why the compilation fails.

Comment: And if we want to pass a parameter to that function?

Comment: if you need to pass parameters use SAM interfaces. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54564239/6305235

Answer (score 1):

Put `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` in build.gradle

Then you can create Binding Adapter like

```
@JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter("onDelayedClick")
fun onDelayedClick(view: View, function: () -> Unit) {
    // TODO: Do something
}
```

And XML Like

```
<View
   android:id="@+id/test_view"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:onDelayedClick="@{viewModel.testFunction}"/>
```

And VM Like

```
val testFunction =  {
    // TODO: Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [Event Handling](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#event_handling) section I came across this line:

In Listener Bindings, only your return value must match the expected return value of the listener (unless it is expecting void)

For more about error :

> cannot generate view binders java.lang.StackOverflowError

read [this](https://n8ebel.github.io/2017-07-27-bug-busting-databinding-onLongClick/) article. hope it will help you!!

Answer (score -1):

The declaration `() -> Unit` suggests a function which takes no input and returns nothing (`Unit` is the return type in this statement). Your function should look like this:

```
fun testFunction() = {}
```

Comment: The databinding compiler throws the same exception (cannot generate view binders java.lang.StackOverflowError) if I change the `Unit` return to `{}`. Just so you are aware, returning Unit is exactly the same as returning an empty block, you can check the Kotlin bytecode yourself to see that this is the case. I had just written it like that to keep the example as simple as possible.

Comment: @EricBachhuber Did you find a fix ? Because I saw other post saying that maybe a possible bug of kotlin / databinding.

Comment: @Dex Sebas no fix that I know of, as far as I know it's a bug in the databinding compiler. The workaround I'm using is to use a different return type in the parameter (i.e. `function: () -> Boolean` instead of `function: () -> Unit`), but it's hacky and requires changing the return type of the function that is being called which is not always possible (and poor design, imo).

Comment: And in your layout / kt file class you're binding like this ? "@{viewModel.itemClick()}" or "@{() -> viewModel.itemClick()}" /// class fun itemClick() : Boolean {
       Log.e("test", "test")
       return true
   }

Comment: I've tried both, but neither work. I opened an issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78197871

Comment: @Dex Sebas sorry, I misread your comment. For the workaround, parameter `function: () -> Boolean` `@{() -> viewModel.itemClick()}` and then `fun itemClick(): Boolean { return true }` would work fine (compiles without StackOverflowError and functions properly in the app)

Comment: Yes, I did  fun itemClick() : Boolean {
       Log.e("test", "test")
       return true
   } but its not compiling. I added the code in the issueTracker of google.

Comment: Okay, I have not used multiple binding parameters (i.e. @BindingAdapter("adapter", "action") so cannot speak to that. But with just one parameter (i.e. `function () -> Boolean`) it works fine. Do you get a StackOverflowException as well?

Comment: Yes, seems like a bug maybe? Because it not works with multiple binding parameter. I just saw after a invalidate cache a error 'Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:action' with parameter type lambda' but with only one parameter works fine (using Boolean and not Unit). Sad, it breaks my idea of making a masteradapter for recyclerView