# Higher order function in BindingAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, higher-order-functions, android-binding-adapter

I am using DataBinding in android and I have a custom view: [CarouselView](https://github.com/sayyam/carouselview?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=3289)

I wrote a binding adapter for that:

```
@BindingAdapter("onClick")
fun setOnClick(carouselView: CarouselView, onClick: (position: Int) -> Unit) {
    carouselView.setImageClickListener { position ->
        onClick.run(position)
    }
}
```

And in the xml:

```
<com.synnapps.carouselview.CarouselView
            android:id="@+id/carouselView"
            ...
            app:onClick="@{(p) -> vm.onAdsClicked(p)}"/>
```

But it does not compile. So I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49784193/issue-with-higher-order-function-as-a-binding-adapter/49935889#49935889) answer in the Stackoverflow. But my problem is that I cannot use Runnable instead of kotlin hoc function because I need to pas a parameter to function.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switching from hoc func to the the listener of this custom view worked for me:

```
import com.synnapps.carouselview.ImageClickListener

@BindingAdapter("onClick")
fun setOnClick(carouselView: CarouselView, imageClickListener: ImageClickListener) {
    carouselView.setImageClickListener(imageClickListener)
}
```

Comment: @Andrew `app:onClick="@{(p) -> vm.onAdsClicked(p)}"`

Comment: And how exactly do you define the listener in viewmodel? Wouldn't you get a reference to the view and therefore break the whole intention of viewmodel? And what is "p"?

Comment: @Andrew, no. if you see I'm just passing position. not view. so the code in VM is just a function named `onAdsClicked` with one parameter: `position: Int`

Answer (score 11):

If I may, I had the same issue (passing a param inside a HOF in a `BindingAdapter`) and came up with a more elegant solution. You **can** indeed make this work, you just need define the HOF as a variable first.

**ViewModel:**

```
val onAdsClicked = fun(position: Int) {
// Do stuff
}
```

**XML:**

```
<com.synnapps.carouselview.CarouselView
            android:id="@+id/carouselView"
            ...
            app:onClick="@{vm.onAdsClicked}"/>
```

**BindingAdapter:**

```
@BindingAdapter("onClick")
fun setOnClick(carouselView: CarouselView, onClick: (position: Int) -> Unit) {
    carouselView.setImageClickListener { position ->
        onClick(position)
    }
}
```

Comment: but i don't see how to pass this parameter in xml?

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand your question. If you mean passing the `position` parameter inside XML, you don't need to. It is automatically passed by the `BindingAdapter`. LE: Oh, my bad, I forgot to erase the `run()` call  on the lambda. Try now.

Comment: FYI, added an issue to track this in the DataBinding issue tracker over at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131663967

Comment: I have a problem here, when I use this approach, my livedata values gets erased..