# Typed parameter in a lambda not recognized by the data binder when using BindingAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I am trying to bind the following elements:

xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    ...
    bind:onCheckedChanged="@{(isChecked) -> viewModel.onCheckedChanged(isChecked)}"
    .../>
```

viewModel:

```
class MyViewModel() {
    fun onCheckedChanged(isChecked: Boolean) {
        ...
    }
}
```

using a BindingAdapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("onCheckedChanged")
fun bindOnCheckedChanged(view: SwitchCompat, onCheckedChanged: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
    view.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
        { _, isChecked ->
            if (view.isPressed) onCheckedChanged(isChecked)
        }
    )
}
```

The error I get is this one:

> data binding error ****msg:cannot find method
>   onCheckedChanged(java.lang.Object) in class
>   MyViewModel

It seems that the data binder does not recognize `isChecked` as a `Boolean`. I tried to force the typing in the xml like `isChecked:Boolean` but I get a bunch of different errors.

Right now I made it work by using `Any` instead of `Boolean` but I feel like it's wrong:

```
@BindingAdapter("onCheckedChanged")
fun bindOnCheckedChanged(view: SwitchCompat, onCheckedChanged: (Any) -> Unit) {
    ...
```

and

```
fun onCheckedChanged(isChecked: Any) {
    val isSwitchChecked = isChecked as? Boolean ?: return
    ...
```

Does anyone know how to make it work the correct function signature?

Comment: Did you try `bind:onCheckedChanged="@{viewModel::onCheckedChanged}"`?

Comment: @Fred I did try -> did no work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Binding Adapters documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters#custom-logic): "Event handlers may only be used with interfaces or abstract classes with one abstract method, as shown in the following example:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:onLayoutChange")
fun setOnLayoutChangeListener(
    view: View,
    oldValue: View.OnLayoutChangeListener?,
    newValue: View.OnLayoutChangeListener?
) {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
      if (oldValue != null) {
          view.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(oldValue)
      }
      if (newValue != null) {
          view.addOnLayoutChangeListener(newValue)
      }
  }
}
```

"
[DB docs never specify you can use Kotlin lambdas in Binding Adapters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46971445/android-databinding-bindingadapter-in-kotlin-does-not-recognize-lambdas#answer-54564239) 
In this case you need to create an interface with only one method like this:

```
interface CustomOnCheckedListener {
    fun onChecked(isChecked: Boolean)
}
```

then your Binding Adapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("onCheckedChanged")
fun bindOnCheckedChanged(view: SwitchCompat, onCheckedChanged: CustomCheckListener) {
    view.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
        { _, isChecked ->
            if (view.isPressed) onCheckedChanged.onChecked(isChecked)
        }
    )
}
```

in your ViewModel class you need to create a function with the same signature of the listener's method:

```
fun onChecked(isChecked: Boolean){
    //some code here
}
```

and in your xml simply pass a reference to your function:

```
"@{viewModel::onChecked}"
```

Comment: Interesting... but how does it look in the xml then?

Comment: @RenaudC. I added the code you need to write in your layout

Comment: So I guess in your interface the function is onChecked() and no doIt(), am I correct?

Comment: @RenaudC. but the impotant thing here is the referenced function must have the same signature of the listener's function, fortunately, the compiler will display an error if the signatures don't match.

Answer (score 2):

### SOLUTION: (KOTLIN)

Use ***lambda*** with ***parameters***

---

### | val lambda: (arg1, arg2, ...) -> Type |

---

1️⃣ ➖ Lambda implementation:

MainActivity.kt

```
val lambda: (TextView?) -> Unit = {
    Log.i(TAG, "lambda: ${it?.text}")
}
```

---

2️⃣ ➖ BindingAdapter implementation:

Bindings.kt

```
@BindingAdapter("lambda")
fun View.lambda(block: (TextView?) -> Unit) {
    // Your logic
}
```

---

3️⃣ ➖ Use DataBinding and BindingAdapter:

activity_main.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <data>

       <variable
           name="activityMain"
           type="com.veldan.mvi.ui.activities.MainActivity" />
   </data>

   <View
        lambda="@{activityMain.lambda}"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</layout>
```