# How to set even width for button view which supports in all mobile devices

Tags: android, uibutton, android-linearlayout, padding, android-button

I have created Button View programatically inside LinearLayout with VERTICAL orientation. Below is my code for button view

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        int w=Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        params.setMargins(w/3,0,w/3,0);
        button.setLayoutParams(params);
        button.setText("Hello");
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
layout.addView(button);
```

But because of the dimensions ButtonView looks different in some low dimension device.
For ex. below in low dimension

```
 _____
|hello|
|_____|
```

below in high dimension devices,

```
 _____________
|   hello     |
|_____________|
```

When I tried wrap content for width and left, right padding for it. Due to the length of the text inside Button, all ButtonView will not look even.
For Ex.

```
 _____________
| Hello World |
|_____________|


 _______
| hello |
|_______|
```

My goal is to achieve above(mentioned in high dimension) like width for all devices.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use wrapContent for width with a paddingHorizontal value?

Comment: yeah can do that. but in my case, I have multiple button. Each text of button is different. Some text in button is long and some are short. So padding will not be same for all buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do is using different dimens files:

- Create dimens.xml in those folders:

  - res/values-ldpi
  - res/values-mdpi
  - res/values-hdpi
  - res/values-xhdpi
  - res/values-xxhdpi
  - res/values-xxxhdpi
- In those files define a button size for each density:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="button_width">200dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

- then, get this value in your code:

```
int dp = (int) (getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.test) / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
```

According with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121028/load-dimension-value-from-res-values-dimension-xml-from-source-code), you have to divide the result by the phone density.