# Activity Idle Timeout for ActivityRecord

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, android-activityrecord

So I have a strange problem, and I'm not entirely sure what all information I should provide, but I'll do my best -- just let me know if I need to add more info. I'm having an issue that when I finish my `Activity` and return to the previous `Activity` (or launch it with a new `Intent` -- the problem seems to be centered on finishing the `Activity`) the UI performance drops drastically for about six or seven seconds, then returns to normal.

From `LogCat`, this warning appears consistently:

```
07-11 22:09:42.594: W/ActivityManager(292): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
07-11 22:09:42.601: W/ActivityManager(292): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{42bf6e00 com.kcoppock.sudokubeta/com.kcoppock.sudoku.SudokuBoardActivity}
```

As soon as the activity times out, UI performance returns to normal. Until that point it is very sluggish. I have no code that I am aware of that could be blocking the main thread, and I've even gone so far as to comment out my entire `onPause()` method to see if it makes any difference, and it does not.

The `Activity` does not spawn any background threads, does not perform any network activity, the only disk access it has is some accessing of `SharedPreferences`. The previous questions I've been able to locate are about idle timeouts for `HistoryRecord`, not `ActivityRecord`.

Any ideas what would cause this? Or how I could go about determining what is blocking the UI thread, if that is what is happening?

**EDIT** : Okay, just tried commenting out *everything* except super.onCreate() and setContentView() -- the problem still persists. It doesn't occur with any other Activities but this one, but there's **NOTHING TO** this one. :/

Comment: Technically it is possible to block the UI thread w/ `SharedPreferences`, but I guess it's probably not as likely as a network access or something. Have you tried removing it somehow?

Comment: @AlexLockwood Thanks for the idea. Just tried that; removed all references to any SharedPreferences, commented out my onPause() and onResume(), but no difference.

Comment: kcoppock also see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053090/flash-toggle-button-crash-android

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Oh geez. One of those things that's pretty hard to diagnose outside of trial and error, but I've figured it out. For reference, should anyone else have this problem, it came down to a custom view in my layout. I had added a `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()` to do some layout modifications after the layout pass, but within that listener I modified the layout and thus caused another layout, essentially creating an infinite loop (but somehow not causing an ANR). My solution was like so:

```
private class BoardLayoutListener implements OnGlobalLayoutListener {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        //...do stuff here

        //REMOVE this listener so that you don't repeat this forever
        ViewTreeObserver obs = SudokuBoard.this.getViewTreeObserver();
        obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
    }
}
```

This solution is quite ironic, considering my [second highest rated answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142090/how-do-you-to-retrieve-dimensions-of-a-view-getheight-and-getwidth-always-r/4406090#4406090) specifically deals with this. :P

*sigh*

Comment: hahahah... don't worry, a few weeks ago I was reading answers on SO, and one of them was particularly enlightening so I went to upvote... turns out I answered the question 1.5 years ago and I didn't remember a thing :P

Comment: Here's why there is no AnR : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/TfkPlN5b-ig (Thank you Mother Dianne)

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue today but as it turned out to have a different cause and solution I decided to add the information here just in case it might help someone else.
In my case problem was caused because I had the following line inside my `onActivityResult()` method:
`android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();`
I Just deleted the line and the problem was gone. 
This line is usually used to synchronize the debugger with the OS threads but I just figured it shouldn't be used anywhere. Oddly the problem would not appear until I had my phone disconnected from the desktop.

Regards