# Measure view in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I need to know ImageView width and height. Is there a way to measure it in fragment ? In standard Activity I use this :

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    image.getWidth();
    image.getHeight();
}
```

But where can I use `image.getWidth();` and `image.getHeight();` in fragment ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the [GlobalLayoutListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142090/how-do-you-to-retrieve-dimensions-of-a-view-getheight-and-getwidth-always-r).  You assign the listener to your `ImageView` in `onCreateView()` just like you do in that answer in the link.  It also is more reliable than `onWindowFocusChanged()` for the main Activity so I recommend switching strategies.

**EDIT**

Example:

```
final View testView = findViewById(R.id.view_id);
ViewTreeObserver vto = testView.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
  @Override
  public void onGlobalLayout() {
    Log.d("TEST", "Height = " + testView.getHeight() + " Width = " + testView.getWidth());
    ViewTreeObserver obs = testView.getViewTreeObserver();
    obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
  }
});
```

Comment: To add to this answer... I tried to use this snippet to get the width and height for an ImageView in a fragment displayed by ActionBar Tab listener. (Using support.V4 api, targeting API14+) I had to place the snippet into the 'onViewCreated' method(?) to get results.
In fact in 'onCreateView' the testView object was null, View not found, and this caused exception.

Comment: You should be able to apply it to the view you return in onCreateView though.  The reason it would return null would be because `profileContainer` doesn't exist yet.

Comment: What are profilePadding and profileContainer types?

Comment: @StealthRabbi They are both `View` objects or anything that descends from `View`.

Comment: @DeeV Not a very good explanation for the profilePadding and profileContainer types.

Comment: @KarlMorrison  They're `View`s.  The method `View#addOnGlobalLayoutListener` is a method in `View`.  `profilePadding` I think was a copy-paste error, so I edited to correct references.

Comment: You need to check that testView.getHeight() or testView.getWidth() is not equal to 0 before stop observing with removeOnGlobalLayoutListener due you can get onGlobalLayout call some times with (0,0)