# Still, cannot get image size inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680499/how-to-get-the-width-and-height-of-an-android-widget-imageview), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352920/measure-view-in-fragment), and any other else. But it always returns 0. Or do I miss something?

This is my code :

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo_editor, container, false);

        img = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.photo_editor_img);
        watermark = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.photo_editor_watermark);

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13){
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            screenWidth = size.x;
        }
        else screenWidth = display.getWidth();

        ViewTreeObserver vto = watermark.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                watermarkWidth = watermark.getWidth();
                watermarkHeight = watermark.getHeight();
            }
        });

        vto = img.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                scale = (float) (img.getWidth()/screenWidth);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
```

I've tried to replace those codes inside `onResume` and `onActivityCreated`, but still returns 0.

And this is my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/photo_editor_root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/photo_editor_img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/bg" />

        <ImageView  android:id="@+id/photo_editor_watermark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/watermark"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4680660/2382964

Comment: if you are using `wrap_content` for imageView and no image has set, then it will return size zero. Try setting any images in xml if you havent.

Comment: BTW, you are missing `super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);` Not that it will fix something...

Comment: @vakman I've set an image into my ImageView, I've added my xml..

Comment: @helleye I've never used that code line in every onCreateView and never got an error, I don't really know what it is for, though..

Comment: I checked the code in super class and it does nothing (only returns null). However, personally I think it is a good practice to call the super class every time you override a method, unless there is a specific reason no to do it.   
One note here: You have posted the xml containing **photo_editor_root_layout**, but you are inflating **fragment_photo_editor**.

Comment: @helleye hm..ok, thank you for that. I'll add it right away. photo_editor_root_layout is the id, but the xml file name is fragment_photo_editor

Comment: I failed again... But I have a better hint. Can you put a log message inside your onGlobalLayout()? I see that you are not removing the listener, so maybe it is called more than once, and the last time it is called you have value of 0, but maybe previous times it is fine (if you check the links to the second SO question you have provided, there you will see `removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this)`)

Comment: one doubt, are you using 9png as images and if it is what are their sizes (size as in resolution h,w)?

Comment: @helleye I've tried that one also (removing the listener), yet it's still the same..

Comment: @vakman nope, I didn't use any 9png..It's just an ImageView that I've already set its image resource via xml.

Comment: Is it drawing properly? Or just have problem with reading measurements?

Comment: @vakman it force closed even before the app displays the layout..