# Measure view size after screen rotation

Tags: android, measure

I am using this to measure view size:

```
int widthMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(toExpandVystrahy.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
int heightMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
textVystrahy.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
int vystrahyHeight = textVystrahy.getMeasuredHeight();
```

I have this code in my `onActivityCreated` inside fragment. It works great and measures correctly when I first start my application. However when I change screen orientation and run this method from `onActivityCreated` inside fragment it still returns the same value like before rotation. So where should I measure view height after screen rotation? Isnt `onActivityCreated` correct place?

Thanks in forward

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352920/measure-view-in-fragment

Answer (score 0):

In your Custom View override onMeasure method and get the size of you View with getMeasuredWidth() and getMeasuredHeight()

I do something like this.

```
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int width, int height) {
        super.onMeasure(width,height);
        int w = getMeasuredWidth();
        int h = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
```