# When should I get Width View in Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I adding View (button) programally in Linearlayout.LinearLayout is layouted by XML in Fragment.

I want to get button width, but always return 0.

I googled this problem,

getWidth work only onWindowFocusChanged.

```
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) { }
```

but Fragment do not have this method.

How to get View width in Fragment?

Answer (score 10):

I'd had a similar problem and solved it in the Fragment callback onViewCreated() like this:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    view.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do operations or methods involved
            // View.getWidth(); or View.getHeight();
            // here
        }
    });
}
```

run() runs after all views were rendered...

Answer (score 8):

Check out post [GlobalLayoutListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142090/how-do-you-to-retrieve-dimensions-of-a-view-getheight-and-getwidth-always-r). You can use the listener on your `Button` in `onCreateView()` as you have used `onWindowFocusChanged`. It also is more reliable than `onWindowFocusChanged()`.

Try out as below:

> ```
>   final View myView = profileContainer.findViewById(R.id.sub_page_padding);
>   ViewTreeObserver vto = profilePadding.getViewTreeObserver();
>   vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
>     @Override
>     public void onGlobalLayout() {
>       Log.d("TEST", "Height = " + myView.getHeight() + " Width = " + myView.getWidth());
>       ViewTreeObserver obs = profilePadding.getViewTreeObserver();
>       obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
>     }
>   });
> ```

Comment: This works but I really hate this approach, makes for bloated code.  Just wish there was an en event for when everything is finished layout for a fragment.