# GridView android 75x75 exact screen size of square

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I want to make a GridView that contains 75dp width and 75dp height imageView. And also i want this square fill the screen size, with no space in between. Right now i am just using 500 count. So its randomly printing 500 square images. Its not filling up the space. Please check the image below for tablet version.

[image]

Here is my Adapter:

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return 500;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
            // attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(75, 75));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sample_0);
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

Comment: You want 500 of them to fill the screen, or you want as many 75 x 75 pixeled images as it needs to fill the screen?  In either case, you will need to get the display height and width and then do some calculations.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What's the reason to put all the colorful views?

Comment: i want 75x75 to fill the screen. I am using for the game.

Answer (score 0):

In `getCount` you could divide the area of the screen by the area of the squares you're filling it with.

```
public int getCount() {
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int area = size.x * size.y;
    // TODO: you may want to pass in the square dimensions or make them constants
    return area / (75 * 75);
}
```

Of course, this isn't right, since it uses the display and not the parent ViewGroup. Instead of trying to do this all in the adapter, have the constructor for this take in the dimensions of the parent and do the math there, saving an instance variable with the count:

```
private int numBoxes = 0;
private static final SQUARE_SIZE = 75;
public ImageAdapter(Context c, ViewGroup parent) {
    mContext = c;
    numBoxes = (parent.getWidth() * parent.getHeight()) / (SQUARE_SIZE * SQUARE_SIZE);
}
public int getCount() {
    return numBoxes;
}
```

Comment: Hi Nick,Thank you. I tried the later. When i run the code. its not printing anything. numBoxes = (parent.getWidth() * parent.getHeight()) / (SQUARE_SIZE * SQUARE_SIZE); looks like returning 0

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer by Nick White, you need to make sure the parent layout has been laid out before you can get the height and width. If the parent width and/or height are "wrap_content" or "match_parent", the getHeight() and getWidth() will return zero in the adapter's constructor, if the adapter is being created in the Activity onCreate().

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142090/how-do-you-to-retrieve-dimensions-of-a-view-getheight-and-getwidth-always-r) gives a way to listen for onLayout events and handle sizing. I did try to do something similar, but I found the results in my case were less than perfect, as the grid would draw then redraw after I applied the size changes. So far the best results I've had with grid sizing is to use qualified resource values to size the image views inside the grid. The resource size value is then set according to the screen density or size by creating various values in values-xxx resource folders.

In my case, I was altering the size of the cell images to make a certain number fit the screen by applying something like:

> Integer size = getResources().getInteger(R.int.image_size));
>
> imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(size, size));

It should be possible to do something similar to calculate the number of columns for the screen size.