# getHeight of layoutview inside a listitem

Tags: android, view, horizontallist

I have a `horizontal list` and each list item has a background fill view that
is supposed to be a certain percentage of the height of another view (bottleoverlay) inside the listview.

It all works except I can't find the height of the bottleoverlay view using `getHeight()`
as said in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142090/how-do-you-to-retrieve-dimensions-of-a-view-getheight-and-getwidth-always-r). 
I've tried to use onGlobalLayout listener as suggested but the fill height for all items are the same no matter what values are used when setting  `layoutparams.height`

Is there an easier way to do this, the `bottleheightoverlay` is the same for each item in the list.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// varible declaration... 

// getView that displays the data at the specified position in the data set.
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       ......
       ......
      //increase height of filler
      int bottleHeight =  gridView.findViewById(R.id.bottleoverlay).getHeight();
      FrameLayout backgroundfill = (FrameLayout) gridView.findViewById(R.id.backroundfillbar);

      double percent =  products.get(position).value/ products.get(0).value;
      backgroundfill.getLayoutParams().height = (int) ( (bottleHeight/percent));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it working using the globallayout listener
this is my in imageAdapter

```
      if(!heightSet ){

      final LinearLayout tv = (LinearLayout) gridView.findViewById(R.id.bottleover);
       ViewTreeObserver vto = tv.getViewTreeObserver();
      vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

          @Override
          public void onGlobalLayout() {

              bottleheight = tv.getHeight();
              heightSet = true;
              System.out.println("bottle hiegiht " + bottleheight);
              //turn off listenter
              ViewTreeObserver obs = tv.getViewTreeObserver();

              if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                  obs.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
              } else {
                  obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
              }
          }

      });
      }
```