# How to know the height of the text in a text view with specific text size?

Tags: android, textview, height

In the `layout`, I have a `textview` with `height wrap_content`. The `text size` is 10 sp. So I want to know the exact height of the text.

The reason that I want to know the `height` is, I want to use image span to display some `bitmap` images in the text view. And the decode method needs the target width and height.

Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: TextView.getLayout().getHeight()

Comment: TextView.getLayout is not available when I try to get this in adapter's getView method. I think at that time that value is null.

Comment: what you mean "is not
available" ?

Comment: ok, seems that layout phase is nor execured yet, you would need to run the code i posted before in a Runnable that you. pass to textview.post method

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you to retrieve dimensions of a view? Getheight() and Getwidth() always return zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142090/how-do-you-to-retrieve-dimensions-of-a-view-getheight-and-getwidth-always-r)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the heigth by the textview object:

```
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.<ID_OF_TEXTVIEW_IN_LAYOUT);
    int textViewHeigth = text.getHeigth();
```

Comment: No, getHeight returns 0. getMeasuredHeight also returns 0. I call that method in adapter's getView function.

Answer (score 0):

In activity `onCreate()` override `onGlobalLayout` method of your layout. This method is called after all views are computed. Get the textView height there.
Assuming that your TextView is in a RelativeLayout

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
relativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        relativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);
        int textViewHeigth = text.getHeigth();

        //Do what you want
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override onWindowFocusChanged method and here you can get the actual height and width of your view.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) {
        // the height will be set at this point
        int textViewHeigth = text.getHeigth();
}
```

Here some post for you: 
[getHeight returns 0 for all Android UI objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142090/how-do-you-to-retrieve-dimensions-of-a-view-getheight-and-getwidth-always-r/4406090#4406090)
 and another one [How do you to retrieve dimensions of a view? Getheight() and Getwidth() always return zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142090/how-do-you-to-retrieve-dimensions-of-a-view-getheight-and-getwidth-always-r/4406090#4406090)

Answer (score 0):

There are two APIs in TextView which could be used. They are getTextSize and getLineHeight. Thanks for all the answer and help.