# How to change the Swappable area length in Swipe refresh layout android

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I'm using `SwipeRefreshLayout` from `appcompact rev22` but i want to know if there is a way to change the area length which i can pull down to show the refresh indicator i don't want it to work over all the screen height 
is this can be done? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Use `setDistanceToTriggerSync(int distance)` if you're on API 21 +. To get an idea of what magnitude `distance` should be, if you look at the source code of `SwipeRefreshLayout.java` the default value is 64 x `DisplayMetrics`' density.

See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26580181/6003174

Comment: setDistanceToTriggerSync(int distance) is to set the value that the swiperefresh layout will start refreshing after it,