# get image view position with wrap contant drawable image

Tags: android, image, view, get, position

I have a problem with getting image view top and left position.

My image view is set in center of a relative layout.
When I use `getleft()` and  `getTop()` the result for me is 0 and 0.

my layout file is :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rlMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is really emergency for me.

My issue:

I wrote a code for move and zooming image view and that work correctly but in first click, image view position changing to 0, 0 and I want to get default position for prevent change in first click.

Comment: Show us your current code? when do you call `getLeft()` and `getTop()`?

Comment: i define my image view by id and want Toast its position , how can i toast image view position on api level 8?

Comment: Do you call `getLeft()` and `getTop()` in onCreate?

Comment: yes when call getTop() and  getLeft() i see 0 , 0 but my image set on center of screen and 0, 0 is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I get what you mean, but you can try:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
img.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener(){

                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {

                    int left = img.getLeft();
                    int top = img.getTop();
                    //Toast the height and top...
                }

            });
```

Since the image will not be rendered yet into the screen in `onCreate` therefore you will always get 0 when you call `getLeft()` and `getTop()`

More explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142090/how-do-you-to-retrieve-dimensions-of-a-view-getheight-and-getwidth-always-r/4406090#4406090)

**EDIT**

Set the layout width and height of imageview to wrap_content

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rlMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks but my problem is still alive, my imageview is on center of screen but left and top return zero..

Comment: `android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"` Your layout code says it's `fill_parent`, try changing to `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0):

int location[]=new int[2];

rlBoard.getLocationOnScreen(location);

You can also use getX and getY method of imageview but this method works from api 11

Comment: thanks can describe this piece of code? i dont use it!

Comment: rlBoard is the relative layout object and location is integer array and method getLocatiOnScreen fill the array with relative layout center on screen

Comment: thanks again,  my problem still alive! i use api 8 and cant get image view object position on run time... :(