# Get height and padding size

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I want to see the sum of textview's height and of textview's padding.
I set padding with method:

```
textView.setPadding(0,x,0,x);
```

But if I use

```
textView.getHeight();
```

I will receive 0.

If I use

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();
Log.d(TAG,params.height+"");
```

I will receive -2 that's impossible.

What have I to do?

Edit: This is the XML code

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/try"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Edit2: I use this code for setting width of text view and it work correctely.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
final int width = size.x;
final int height = size.y;
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();
params.width = width/2;
```

I don't want to set the height programmately because I set a padding. But I want to get the measure

Edit3:

I try to use

```
Rect bounds = new Rect();
textView.getPaint().getTextBounds(textView.getText(), 0,textView.getText().length(), bounds); 
bounds.height(); //This should give you the height of the wrapped_content
```

as Slartibartfast told me. But there is a problem:

Probably this is the measurement of text size... But it isn't the correct measurement of height of textview. I tried to sum this number and the 2 measure of padding and try to set:

```
params.height = bounds.height() + 2*x;
```

The view is smaller than the view without this line of code.

Comment: -2 usually means you've used MATCH_PARENT or WRAP_CONTENT (these are assigned constants) as the height property. Can you paste the xml for the textview as well?

Comment: Done edit! This is my code! Is possible to calculate the real height in a wrap_content view?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at : [How to retrieve the dimensions of a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142090/how-do-you-to-retrieve-dimensions-of-a-view-getheight-and-getwidth-always-r/4406090#4406090)

Basically the size is known only after the layout is finished, one way is to create a custom text view and use onSizeChanged method

**EDIT:**

How about

```
Rect bounds = new Rect();
textView.getPaint().getTextBounds(textView.getText(), 0,textView.getText().length(), bounds); 
bounds.height(); //This should give you the height of the wrapped_content
```

Comment: I have read that getHeight() is deprecated and I have to use getSize(Point x). But I don't understand how to use it for this situation. I use it for setting the width of TextView in the way that now I will edit