# Set buttons height to 1/3 of its width

Tags: android, button, height, width

I have two buttons in xml like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">





    <Button
       android:background="@drawable/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>


    </LinearLayout>





</ScrollView>
```

However the buttons appear square while my image's height is 1/3 of its width.
How can I make the buttons height 1/3 of its width?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use ImageButton instead of Button and then set the height as match_parent.

Something like this :

```
   <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: The difference with just Button is that I can set button's height with "dp" (something thath cant happen with ImageButton) but  it won't fit in all screens

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
Button b = findViewById(R.id.button);
b.setHeight(b.getWidth() / 3);
```

Comment: this will return zero. you should do it like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142090/how-to-retrieve-the-dimensions-of-a-view/4406090#4406090

Comment: No.. nothing happened.. I also create a button programmatically but without success... It appears square...