# Bit map falling off screen

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have a bitmap image that I'm trying to keep on the screen it stops at the top but always falls at the bottom. I don't know why it does this and my book is telling me its right.It is a game that involves gravity and boosting but my ship can boost to the top of the screen but never fails to fall off the screen.  Here is my code.

```
private final int GRAVITY=-12;
//stop ship from leaving the screen
private int maxY;
private int minY;
// limit the bounds of the ships speed
private  final int MIN_SPEED=1;
            private final int MAX_SPEED= 20;

private Bitmap bitmap;
private int x,y;
private int speed = 0;
// Constructor
public PlayerShip(Context context, int screenX, int screenY){
    boosting= false;
    x=50;
    y=50;
    speed=1;
    bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            context.getResources(), R.drawable.ship);
    maxY=bitmap.getHeight()-screenY;
    minY=00;
}
public void update (){


    //ARE WE BOOSTING
    if (boosting) {
        //speed up
        speed += 2;
            }
    else {
        //SLOW DOWN
        speed-=5;
    }
    if ( speed> MAX_SPEED){
        speed=MAX_SPEED;
    }
    // Never Stop Completely
    if (speed <MIN_SPEED){
        speed = MIN_SPEED;
    }
    //move the ship up or down
    y-=speed+ GRAVITY;
    //BUT DON'T LET SHIP STRAY OFF SCREEN
    if ( y<minY){
        y=minY;
    }
    if(y<maxY){
        y=maxY;

}x++;}

//Getters
public Bitmap getBitmap(){
    return bitmap;
}
 public int getSpeed(){
 return speed;
  }
 public int getX(){
    return x;
}
public int getY() {
return y;
}

public void setBoosting() {

     boosting = true;
}
public void stopBoosting(){
    boosting=false;
}
```

}

Comment: Where are you initialising `PlayerShip`? Remember, UI components only get their height after `OnGlobalLayout`. So you will need to [debug your small program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and check to see if the value is correct

Comment: I initialized it one of my other classes GameActivity

Comment: In which method though? Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142090/how-to-retrieve-the-dimensions-of-a-view/4406090#4406090)

Comment: Hang on I don't think I worded my question right the bitmap isn't what is falling I am trying to set a boundary for the bottom so that it doesn't keep falling if that makes sense.@DavidRawson