# Screen Size Honeycomb Menu android

Tags: android, size, screen, android-3.0-honeycomb

Hi I am trying yo get the screen size of screen minus the menu bar at the bottom.

I know I could just subtract a constant number according to the resolution of the device but it is a super ugly hack. I am sure google people are not dumb enough to forget to give the user a function to get the height of the bottom menu bar so I can subtract it from the full screen size

This is a similar post. 
[Size of android notification bar and title bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600713/size-of-android-notification-bar-and-title-bar)

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

what_i_need =metrics.heightPixels-buttomMenuHeight();
```

I need buttomMenuHeight();

i could not find it in the API. I don't really care about the backward comparability at this point

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not use the height of the activity's top-level View? e.g. if your activity contains a full-height LinearLayout, use its height, so you don't have to know the menu height, or noticiation bar height.

I think you're treading a dangerous road doing this kind of calculation, as you don't know what the future layouts for Android might be, or how they might differ on Google TV, or whatever.

Comment: I am drawing image in native code and I need to pass the size of the screen to C.
I tried to get the Height by getHeight() of the view but that returns 0 always even after setContentView is called.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling getHeight() after onLayout.  The view is not sized on inflate.

EDIT:
Or since Activity does not have onLayout you might wait for onSizeChanged.

(Reference [How to know when activity is laid out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386468/how-to-know-when-activity-is-laid-out/3386531#3386531))

Answer (score 0):

I am drawing image in native code and I need to pass the size of the screen to C.

I tried to get the Height by getHeight() of the view but that returns 0 always even after setContentView is called.

```
RelativeLayout masterLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
masterLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
setContentView(masterLayout);
```

when I try masterLayout.getHeight(), it returns 0.
I expected to get the full screen height as I said fill_parent.