# How to calculate the android 3.0(tablet) system bar height?

Tags: android

How to calculate the android 3.0 tablet screen bottom system bar(contain back button,menus button,etc)height?

Comment: Interesting question, just curious - why would you want to know this?

Comment: Is this similar question useful for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173926/screen-size-honeycomb-menu-android

Answer (score 0):

Chris Banes mentioned this in a recent Droidcon talk. The whole talk is super relevant, but here's a link to the part that answers your question (for all form factors, including tablet).

https://youtu.be/_mGDMVRO3iE?t=1093

This is the correct way to get status bar and navigation bar sizes: [setOnApplyWindowListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View,%20android.support.v4.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener))

I hope this helps!